# Kendo Grid - 'null' appearing for null date - universal workaround?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We're currently using Kendo version 2012.2.710.340, and I know that this version had an issue with null date columns being displayed as 'null'. I know also know that this can be worked around using a template with a condition to check for null.

However, is there any global fix for this? We use numerous grids throughout our application, and I don't want to have to add a fix for every single column we bind in each grid.

Alternatively, is this fixed in newer builds? I remember seeinga forum post saying it would appear in the next release a few months ago, but can't seem to find any reference to it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fixed - `null` is no longer displayed. Empty string is displayed instead. Try a newer version.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for other nullable fields?